# NgRx effect "dies" after 10 errors

Tags: typescript, error-handling, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Using NgRx in an Angular project, I have the following effects:

```js
let i = 0

@Injectable()
export class Effects {
    testEffect$ = createEffect(
        () =>
            this.actions$.pipe(
                tap(() => console.log("action number:", i += 1)),
                mergeMap(() => throwError(() => "")),
            ),
        { dispatch: false, useEffectsErrorHandler: true },
    )

    // ...
```

For any action that is dispatched, the effect logs a statement and then replaces its content by an error.

This works for 10 actions. After exactly 10 actions have been dispatched, the 11th action will not cause the `console.log` anymore. In fact, no effect is executed at all anymore and Redux Dev tools also do not record any actions from that point on.

I realize that if I expect errors to occur, I should use `catchError` to gracefully handle them. However, it worries me that if there is an error I do not handle, it can break my entire application after occurring a few times.

Why does this happen? Is there a way I can prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended behavior.

We found this a good starting point for most projects.

You can override this behavior by creating your own error handler, and configuring `Effects` to use it.

For more info and an example see https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle#customizing-the-effects-error-handler